# Attempting to present <**> on <**> while a presentation is in progress. While performing a segue from one view controller to another using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue, uipinchgesturerecognizer

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let pinchGesture:UIPinchGestureRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pinchGesture")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func pinchGesture(){

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("trick1Segue", sender: self)

}
```

In my iOS app, i want to transition to a different view controller when  a pinch gesture is performed on the screen.
The tap gesture is to dismiss the keyboard when tapped outside the keyboard area

While running the app, I get an error message:

"Attempting to present < ** > on < ** > while a presentation is in progress"

The new view controller appears but opens twice, with a very short time difference. Looked up a lot of blogs but couldn't find a solution, please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `pinchGesture` can be called multiple times.  You should add a property to your viewController to keep track of the fact that you already have acted upon the pinch gesture:

```
var segueInProcess = false

func pinchGesture() {
    if !segueInProcess {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("trick1Segue", sender: self)
        segueInProcess = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been struggling with this issue for quite a while            Solved now!!!

Answer (score 0):

Gesture recognizers are called multiple times with different states. What you can do is check the `state` property of the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` in `pinchGesture()`.